# How to disable value on the select option ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My component is like this :

```
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
    {{selected}}
  </div>
</div>

var demo = new Vue({
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
      options: [{
        id: '',
        name: 'Select Category'
      }]
    };
  },
  ...
})
```

See full code and demo here : https://fiddle.jshell.net/oscar11/stvct9er/5/

I want disable "Select Category". So "Select category" disabled. User can not select it. User can only choose a value other than "Select Category".

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm on mobile so can't post a full answer, but will optgroup suffice?

Comment: @Adrian Wragg, What do you mean by "optgroup"?

Comment: I see you have an accepted answer already, but `optgroup` can be used inside `select` tags in order to provide a heading for a group of options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add `option` directly in `select` tag.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>
  <option value="" disabled>Select a category</option>
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Also, remove it from `data` function.

```
data() {
  return {
    selected: '',
    options: []
  };
}
```

I don't recommend you to add this option in the `options` array, because it is a `placeholder` attribute for your `select`.

Comment: What if you want to enable/disable it programatically?

Answer (score 11):

Other option could be to disable that element using a binding

```
<option v-for="option in options" 
        :disabled="!option.id"
        v-bind:value="option.id">
    {{ option.name }}
</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for information about `:disabled="!option.id"`.